# localhost:3000 will not update my css, or will not load at all when static files are deleted of switch off

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, localhost, assets

I have been trying to work on my rails project since I precompiled the assets to deploy to Heroku. The css would not update, so I followed the advice of other similar entries and deleted the static file. The app would then never load, it would just be in a state of buffer. I have also tried to simply set the config.serve_static_files to false. After running a rake assets clean, I have the same result. I have also tried dscacheutil -flushcache, to not effect.

my development.rb file:

```
    Rails.application.configure do
      # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

      # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
      # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
      # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
      config.cache_classes = false

      # Do not eager load code on boot.
      config.eager_load = false

      # Show full error reports and disable caching.
      config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

      # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
      config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

      # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
      config.active_support.deprecation = :log

      # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
      config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

      # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
      # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
      # number of complex assets.
      config.assets.debug = false
      config.serve_static_files = false

      # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
      # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
      config.assets.digest = true
      config.assets.compress = true
      # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
      # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
      # Raises helpful error messages.
      config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = false

      # Raises error for missing translations
      # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
    end
```

And just in case my production.rb file:

```
    Rails.application.configure do
      # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

      # Code is not reloaded between requests.
      config.cache_classes = true

      # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
      # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
      # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
      # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
      config.eager_load = true

      # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
      config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

      # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
      # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
      # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
      # NGINX, varnish or squid.
      # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

      # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
      # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
      config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

      # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
      config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
      # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

      # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
      config.assets.compile = false

      # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
      # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
      config.assets.digest = true

      # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

      # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
      # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
      # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

      # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
      # config.force_ssl = true

      # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
      # when problems arise.
      config.log_level = :debug

      # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
      # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

      # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
      # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

      # Use a different cache store in production.
      # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

      # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
      # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

      # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
      # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
      # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

      # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
      # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
      config.i18n.fallbacks = true

      # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
      config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

      # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
      config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

      # Do not dump schema after migrations.
      config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
    end
```

Please help me, I can hardly do any work like this. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried running `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: I cannot even run that it seems. When I do, the command line freezes. The command lays there suspended for an hour

Comment: I was able to run it in the end. Then I saw that my code is now updated. Hopefully, I don't have to asset:precompile every time that I want my css code to be updated... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some trivia for you:

```
rake assets:clean
```

A better way to get rid of *all* precompiled assets is [`rake assets:clobber`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/README.md#rake-task).

This actively removes the files and folders in your `/public/assets` folder, allowing you to get rid of any of the precompiled assets which may be left behind.

--

Another piece of trivia:

Whenever running `rake assets:precompile`, run it with an ENV var:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This ensures the files are pre-compiled using the data & settings that are available in the *production* environment, thus giving you the most reliable files.

---

As my own rule, I always try and ensure local assets are loaded dynamically.

This requires no change on your part (indeed, I'd actually remove the `serve_static_files` line in your `development.rb` file).

The reason for this is that if you're dealing with precompiled assets in development, you're going to have to recompile them each time you want to test if they've changed, both time consuming and unreliable.

`Heroku` should only require asset precompilation for its *production* environment.

---

> I cannot even run that it seems

This suggests a deeper problem, either with your app or Ruby installation.

There are several things you need to do to ensure this is not a major problem:

1. Remove all your `CSS` and `JS` to a temp folder (`Recycle Bin` if necessary), and then run `rake assets:precompile`. There may be an off reference/loop causing the problem
2. Create a new Rails app with `rails new TESTAPP` and then run `rake assets:precompile` immediately. If it works well, you know the problem is with your current app
3. Stop any other running processes. If you've got programs running which could impede the `cmd`, it's going to prevent it running smoothly.
4. If you used the likes of `RubyInstaller` to install your Ruby, you may wish to upgrade. If not, you may wish to upgrade anyway.

Ultimately, if your computer is processing `rake` commands extremely slowly, it suggests a major system issue. You need to make sure it works properly to ensure a smooth development cycle.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative post. I learned so much from this! I performed all your suggestions unfortunately, this sets me back to square one, because now that the static files are gone, the app loads at the rate of frozen molasses, if it ever decides to load. The test indicates that this is an issue with the app itself, since the assets where precompiled with no problem.  So at least there is that.